# Is it legal to sell products whose design uses titles of copyrighted songs?

Tags: copyright, music

There are some similar questions here, but I believe mine is a little different. Is it legal to sell products (t-shirts, mugs, etc.) that use typography art of the titles of famous songs. Also, can these be legally advertised by me, non-copyright holder, with the name of the band, or artists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the typography is a significant aspect of the overall art of a song title - wherever the song title may be reproduced, i.e. poster, CD cover, etc. - than I'd say that's part of the copyright of the artwork as a whole and not simply the title, and is under copyright. Further, individual type faces can be under copyright themselves.

And band names can be trademarked; you will need permission to use the name for products and advertising, since using the name will imply an endorsement from that band.